# iframe redirect from popup

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

iam using an iframe to show some content.On one of the pages its opening an popup which should be printed. after i close this window it should redirect to the start, but in the iframe. How can i do this? Acutally its not redirect in the iframe, it changes the parent.

My code

```
<iframe src="login.php" width="950px" height="600px" frameborder="0">
```

And this is the onunload function which should change the content of the iframe.

```
<script>
window.onunload = function(){
var iframe = opener.parent.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.contentDocument.location.href = "index.html";
// opener.open("index.html"); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: opener.parent.document.getElementById('iframe').src="index.html";
is working